# Is server side pooling necessary for Sequlize pool to work?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, connection-pooling, pgbouncer

I have a nodejs application and I am using *sequelize* as ORM with *Postgres*. As explained in documentation of sequelize, here is my code for pooling.

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize(/* ... */, {
  // ...
  pool: {
    max: 10,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  }
});
```

Since Postgres doesn’t have inbuilt pooling (AFAIK), Do I need to install and configure something like *pgbouncer*, on my server to make pooling work?

Answer (score 0):

No.  Having multiple levels of pooling rarely makes sense, and you can certainly have a client-side pool without a server-side one.